# write text and change image width

Tags: imagemagick

how can you change the width of an image depending on the width of the text?

if you want a 5 pixel padding both to the left and right of the text?

and how can you define the path to the font you want to use?

Comment: Using GD or imagemagick? Please add more info and clarify how you create "the text"

Comment: Everything you need is in here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/ I'm too lazy/busy at the moment to look up the right chapters, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

1. *'How to change width of image depending on width of text?'*

   You can use a really biiiig drawing canvas first and then `-trim` to trim the superfluous space around your text. For example:

   ```
   convert                                         \
      -font "Courier"                              \
      -size 800x200                                \
       xc:none                                     \
      -box green                                   \
      -pointsize 24                                \
      -gravity center                              \
      -draw "text 0,0 'This is clarkk\'s text...'" \
      -trim                                        \
       clarkk.jpeg
   ```
2. *'How to add 5 pixels padding to both left and right of the text?'*

   You can use any of the different ImageMagick methods to add left and right pixels to the resulting image from step 1. For example:

   ```
    convert                                                   \
       clarkk.jpeg                                            \
      -gravity center                                         \
      -extent $(identify -format '%[fx:W+10]x%H' clarkk.jpeg) \
       clarkk-padded.jpeg
   ```
3. *'How to define the path of the font I want to use?'*

   You can use the `-font "/path/to/some directory with/fontname.ttf"` directive.

   ```
   convert                                         \
      -font "/Library/Fonts/Verdana Italic.ttf"    \
      -size 800x200                                \
       xc:none                                     \
      -box green                                   \
      -pointsize 24                                \
      -gravity center                              \
      -draw "text 0,0 'This is clarkk\'s text...'" \
      -trim                                        \
       clarkk-font.jpeg
   ```

   To get a list of fonts which are accessible to ImageMagick, run

   ```
   convert -list font
   ```

Comment: @clarkk: Did these points provide appropriate answers for your 3 questions?

Comment: Hi Kurt. This padding example adds pixels to the left and right of the text. Do you know of a way in imagemagick to produce padding *inside* the image, reducing the resulting -pointsize, and not affecting the -size of the converted image?